# Irreducible factorization

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I fully understand the concept of irreducible factorization, however, is there a method in order to find the irreducible factors?

For example if we have the polynomial $$x^{12}-1$$ in mod $2$

Comment: If everything else fails, there's always brute force: If the polynomial factors, one of the factors must have degree at most 6, so there are less than $2^6=64$ potential factors (with nonzero constant coefficient) to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod 2, $x^{12}-1=(x^{6}+1)^{2}=((x^{3}+1)^{2})^{2}=(((x-1)(x^{2}+x+1))^{2})^{2}$. mod 2, $x^{2}+x+1$ has no roots so is irreducible!

Comment: That fully makes sense but how would one see that $((x^{3}+1)^{2})^{2}=(((x-1)^{2}(x^{2}+x+1))^{2})^{2}$?

Comment: @smith: Clearly $1$ is a root of $x^3+1$, so just divide out $x-1$ by long polynomial division.

Answer (score 0):

$X^n - 1$ factors over the integers (and therefore over any field) as the product of the cyclotomic polynomials $C_k(X)$ for $k$ dividing $n$.   In this case 
$$ X^{12} - 1 = C_1(X) C_2(X) C_3(X) C_4(X) C_6(X) C_{12}(X)\\ = (X-1)(X+1)(X^2+X+1)(X^2+1)(X^2-X+1)(X^4 - X^2 + 1)$$
Of course, over $Z_2$, $+1 = -1$.  If a quadratic factors, the factors must be linear, and the only quadratic factor that has a root in $\mathbb Z_2$ is $X^2+1 = (X + 1)^2$.  $X^4 + X^2 + 1$ has no linear factors, but it does factor into quadratics: since $X^4 + 1 = (X^2 + 1)^2$, $X^4 + X^2 + 1 = (X^2 + 1)^2 + X^2 = (X^2 + X + 1)^2$.

Thus the factorization is

$$X^{12}-1 = (X+1)^4(X^2+X+1)^4$$

Comment: Thank you for this answer, if i could possible ask for a slight extension? .. if a question was to arise asking for the maximum amount of factors for our polynomial $X^{12}-1$ in mod 2, how would i find this?

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum amount of factors"?  What I (and mich95) gave is a factorization into $8$ irreducibles (of which some happen to be the same).  You can't get more factors than that.